# Why does Guardians of the Galaxy start at Volume 2 instead of Volume 1?

Tags: marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy

As in title. Why does *Guardians of the Galaxy* start at [*Volume 2*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(2008_team)) instead of *Volume 1*?

Is the *Volume 1* the old *Guardians of the Galaxy* or something?

Answer (score 16):

[The Guardians of the Galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_%281969_team%29) were created and debuted in 1969, but only appeared as guests or highlighted characters in other books like Marvel Super-Heroes, Marvel Two-In-One, Giant-Sized Defenders, Marvel Presents, The Avengers, et al.

In 1990, they finally received their own self-titled book. It starred a group made up of different members, but using the same name.

[image: Guardians of the Galaxy #1]

It ran for 62 issues before finally being cancelled.

That 1990 series is considered "Volume 1".

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Volume 2 is the second incarnation of the team. The first Guardians of the Galaxy was first published in 1969, and the series was cancelled in 1995. Volume 2 (first published in 2008) starts with Star Lord attempting to reform the Guardians of the Galaxy.